# How to make webpack-dev-server work with Aurelia and not on localhost

Tags: aurelia, webpack-dev-server

I'm working with the webpack aurelia skeleton
https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-es2016-webpack

`> npm run dev`

will build/bundle everything from src/ to dist/, but how to make the webpack-dev-server to work **not** using localhost, so that when changing code in src and saving, the browser will auto-reload (like browser-sync).

I tried playing around with proxy, but it just won't work.

It works only half way now, in that the command above will init a server on localhost:8080 and then I use nginx to proxy that to a "valid" adress. I have full access to nginx, but only port :80

**edit:**
I don't mind webpack-dev-server listening on localport, but the app in the browser should't reguest that, it should request my nginx proxy, ie not:
http://localhost:3000/sockjs-node/info?t=1461747081151, but 
http://myserver.com/sockjs-node/info?t=1461747081151

**edit2:**
I hacked the file index.js directly with the host I wanted, and that kind of worked. It's super dirty and only shows that its possible to get done if only all parameters get properly passed. Next obstacle is to figure out why there now is a SockJS version miss match error :/

Comment: Do you want to change the host? Take a look at webpack.config.js file. You just have to change the parameters

Comment: I tried that, gives "Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL" (might be related to ipv6). This worked fine with browser-sync though